# Airflow- Pass Parameters at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have a DAG. How I can I pass parameters to the DAG at runtime and start the DAG? Basically, the DAG can take upto 10 values for a param (say, number). Based on the number param value passed, the corresponding notebook will be called.

Is there a way to do this in Python programmatically to get the param that the user passes/enters and then, call the DAG?

Comment: How about you store these params in a Database table column and then fetch the value using any custom operator as per your choice and then take action accordingly. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon - Thanks Much! Could you please share any sample that you may have? When you mean store the params in a Database , you mean Databricks Delta Lake or a different database LIKE MYSQL ? Thanks!

Comment: This is the native way to pass params to DAG run. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#passing-parameters-when-triggering-dags

Comment: @Emma, I will be scheduling my DAG and so can inculue my param values in the confg and  invoke the config then?Could you please confirm? Thanks!

Comment: Not quite. The link is for passing when triggering the DAG externally and not for scheduling.  If you are scheduling the DAG, the value is dynamic or static for the DAG meaning does the value change from the one run to the next run?  If static, you can pass static config file to the DAG.  If dynamic, please elaborate on what is the logic of choosing what value to be passed and how you are intended to use the value in the DAG.